# vba save user form contents

Tags: vba, excel, save, userform

I have nearly completed my computing project in 6th form and everything works except for being able to save. The project is a seating plan generator in which a teacher can drag and drop tables onto a user form to build their classroom and then seat all the students to various criteria. I have a Save Plan button which I want to save the objects the have been added to the userform, thus the load Plan button should then allow the teacher to access the userform where they left off.

I have tried the following but they are not working:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

--

```
Dim vSave_File As Variant
vSave_File = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Test.xls", "(*.xls),*.xls", 1, "Dialog Title"
```

Both methods take me through the save as dialogue but when I come to look for them they do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetSaveAsFilename function only returns a filename, it does not save. You should add code that saves the workbook using the vSave_File variable:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vSave_File
```

In addition you may need to specify the filetype, depending on your requirements:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vSave_File, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: That works in saving the workbook however, is there a way I can get it to save all the objects that have been added to the user form when the teachers build their classroom? Because what I would want is for them to be able to come back to plans they have already built to possibly edit them.

Comment: You will have to code that all I'm afraid, so each item that gets added you must somehow add to a list, for instance on a (hidden) worksheet. Then additionally, you will have to add code that is capable of reading that list to restore what's on the form. There is no easy way to do this with a Userform I'm afraid.